# Lead variables on RREF Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a screenshot from a matrix in RREF : http://postimg.org/image/qo5z1ins1/.

I know the system has 2 degree of fredom and i can choose any pair of variables from x1,x2,x3,x4 to be the lead variables.

The most obvious one is and readily shown by the matrix is (x1,x3) as lead variables.But  i can swap column 4 with column 2 yielding (x1,x3) as lead variables.
I can also swap column 2 with column 1 yielding (x2,x3) as lead variables, and maintaining the column 2 swaped i can swap column 3 with column 4 yielding (x2,x3) as lead variables.

My problem is, what operations would we do in the matrix to get (x1,x2) as lead variables or (x3,x4) as lead variables ?

Answer (score 1):

The columns can be swapped at any point during the row reduction, as long as you keep track of which variables go with which column. So if you want $x_3,x_4$ to wind up as lead variables (dependent variables) and the others free, rearrange the original matrix with the $x_3$ and $x_4$ columns first, and then compute the RREF of the new matrix, which should give your $x_3,x_4$ as functions of $x_1,x_2$ when the matrix is turned back into equations.

Comment: Btw, regarding the definition of  a RREF matrix.We dont need the LEADING ( first non-zero element from the left ) to be a pivot ( 1 ), right ? We can have a messy matrix in RREF as long as it has column pivots with a 1 and rest of 0s, and also have only 1 pivot for each row. Is that right ?

Comment: The definition of RREF requires the first nonzero of each row to be 1, among other things. But as far as solving for some variables in terms of others, one does not *have to* only use the lead variables.